# Routing a clients connection to a specific instance of a SignalR backend within a Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, kubernetes, signalr

While trying to create a web application for shared drawing I got stuck on a problem regarding Kubernetes and scaling. The application uses an ASP.NET Core backend with SignalR for sharing the drawing data across its users. For scaling out the application I am using a deployment for each microservice of the system. For the SignalR part though, additional configuration is required.

After some research I have found out about the possibility to sync all instances of the SignalR backend either through the use of Azures SignalR Service or the use of a Redis backplane. The latter of which I have gotten to work on my local minikube environment. I am not really happy with this solution because of the following reasons:

- My main concern is that like this I have created a hard bottleneck in
  the system. Unlike in a chat application where data is sent only once
  in a while, messages are sent for every few points drawn in the
  shared drawing experience by any client. Simply put, a lot of traffic
  can occur and all of it has to pass through the single Redis backplane.
- Additionally to me it seems unneccessary to make all instances of the SignalR backend talk to each
  other. In this application shared drawing does only occur in small groups of up to 10 clients lets
  say. Groups of this size can easily be hosted on a single instance.

So without syncing all instances of the SignalR backend I would have to route the clients connection based on the SignalR group name to the right instance of the SignalR backend when the client is trying to join a group.

I have found out about [StatefulSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) which allow me to have a persistent address for each backend pod in the cluster. I then could somehow associate the SignalR group IDs with the pod addresses they are running on in lets say another look up microservice. The problem with this is that the client needs to be able to access the right pod from outside of the cluster where that cluster internal address does not really help.

Also I am wondering if there isnt a whole better approach to the problem since I am very new to the world of kubernetes. I would be very greatful for your thoughts on this issue and any hint towards a (better) solution.